# python import-ed variable keeps the same value although it is changing

Tags: python, variables

I have the following python code which in my opinion behaves strangely:

Imported module:

```
# ChangeVar.py
def Print1():
    print "1--"

def Print2():
    print "2--"

Print=Print1

def Change():
    global Print
    Print=Print2
```

Main module:

```
#UseVar.py
from ChangeVar import *

Print()
Print()

Change()


Print()
Print()
```

I expect this code to print the follwing:

```
1--
1--
2--
2--
```

But what I get instead is:

```
1--
1--
1--
1--
```

Could someone point me to the right part of the python reference or explain why I don't get the expected behavior?

Thanks,

Iulian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `global` is global to the module only.

```
import ChangeVar

ChangeVar.Print()
ChangeVar.Print()

ChangeVar.Change()

ChangeVar.Print()
ChangeVar.Print()
```

This will work, however, reconsider your use of `global` - it's universally bad practice. There should be a cleaner way to do what you want. Consider using a class inside your module.

```
# ChangeVar.py
class ChangeVar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Print=self.Print1

    def Print1(self):
        print "1--"

    def Print2(self):
        print "2--"

    def Change(self):
        self.Print=self.Print2
```

Used as so:

```
#UseVar.py
from ChangeVar import ChangeVar

cv = ChangeVar()
cv.Print()
cv.Print()

cv.Change()

cv.Print()
cv.Print()
```

I would also like to note that according to the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), `lowercase_with_underscores` is the preferred naming style for functions, and `lowercase` for module names.

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions and I appreciate showing me the cleaner way. To be precise: That `Print` is a logging function and should be called simply with the name of the function (`Print` - not `Module.Print` )

Comment: @INS First of all, I'd recommend a descriptive name - log would be appropriate and not conflict with a builtin. Why do you need it to be called without specifying the namespace? Generally it's a good idea to separate such things.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `from ChangeVar import *`, you create a name `Print` in your main module referring to what `Print` is currently set as in ChangeVar. But that's a separate name pointing to the same function, so calling `Change` doesn't update it in your main module.

There are two ways round it:

- You can do `import ChangeVar` and then call `ChangeVar.Print()`. Because this uses the name in ChangeVar, it is affected by `ChangeVar.Change()`, as @Lattyware says.
- You can create a function `Print` which calls `Print1` or `Print2` depending on what some other variable is set to.